# Прочитать объемную часть файла

Tags: java, файлы

Пишу свой упаковщик файлов на Java в целях практики. Структура архива примерно такая:

1. Размер названия файла.
2. Название файла.
3. Размер файла.
4. Сами байты файла.

И так для каждого файла.

И если при прочтении первых трех пунктов проблем не возникает (использую DataInputStream), то если начать читать весь файл просто в массив байтов, при большом объеме этого файла начнет забиваться оперативная память.

И собственно вопрос: как можно эффективно читать эту часть?

Comment: читайте по кускам, по 4-8-32 кб.

Answer (score 1):

Читайте кусками и используйте промежуточный файловый буфер для больших файлов. Все зависит от задачи для которой вы их считываете